# Is it possible to break up class with too many generics type in Java?

Tags: java

Sometimes I ended up writing some classes with too many generic types

```
class C<T1, T2, T2, T3, T4, T5> { 
...
}
```

Is there a general strategy to break up this pattern?

Comment: Yes, it's called decomposition. How you decompose depends on the requirements of your software. For all we know, you might not even need some of those generic type parameters. You should give more context about your situation

Comment: Here's a clue:  _You_ said it has too many type parameters.  If _you_ think a class that you just finished writing--that's still fresh in your head--has too many type parameters, too many methods, too many instance variables, too many states, too many lines of code, etc., then it probably has _waaaaay_ too many of whatever for somebody _else_ to want to read it.

Answer (score 3):

Create an alternate set of classes: `C1<T1>`, `C2<T2>`, `C3<T3, T4>`, etc.

In the different places where you were using `C`, you'll end up referring to individual subsets of these classes. Instead of:

```
C<String, Integer, Whatever, Thing, ...> x;
```

you'll have:

```
C1<String> x;
C2<Integer> y;
C3<Whatever, Thing> z;
```

A class with that many type parameters is most likely an example of a [god class/object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Comment: While I agree with your answer I think you need to give a lot more explanation here. Generics allow method signatures to change which your solution doesn't. For example, OPs might need a `getX` method and will need to know it's signature.